# ALT key HUD web search in firefox

Tags: firefox, search, hud

Is it possible to conduct a web search (In Firefox 14) from the HUD? (Ubuntu 12.04)

For example, Hitting The ALT key (to bring up the HUD menu for Firefox) and typing in a search term?

It doesn't seem to be a feature currently, and I was wondering, Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: You could easily set a global keybinding to `QUERY=$(zenity --entry) && firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=${QUERY}"`

Comment: @user55822 could you please expand on this comment, possibly as an answer?

Comment: @vasa1, Id rather not since it's not a way to search in FF via HUD. About setting it up: go to **System settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts** -> **Custom** and type in `bash -c 'QUERY=$(zenity --entry) && firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=${QUERY}"'`.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to find anyway to do it, but that is in no was definitive.

If you are just looking for a keyboard shortcut to do a search easily, that is already built into firefox. `Ctrl+k` will send you directly to the search box in the upper right hand corner of your browser.

[Mozilla Help](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly?s=keyboard+shortcuts&r=0&as=s#w_search) gives you all the keyboard shortcuts that are built into Firefox.

I realize that at best this is only a half answer to your actual question but it could still be helpful(I hope).

Comment: Well, It is helpful, so thank you for that. I find it kind of awkward, but It is something. And something tends to be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The features currently incorporated in **HUD includes only the MENU options** of Active application .

Throughout the **Firefox Menu there is no such Option as Search using google or Duck Duck go**, hence you can't search directly through HUD interface. HUD is currently in Active Development , hope such new features are designed in Future.

Comment: OK then. I guess I'll Deal with it for now and try to use the CTRL+K mentioned by Trailrider.

I'm hoping this feature is eventually implemented of course. Thanks for the help, all of you!